# Script bat, Windows can not find .exe

Tags: c#, c++, windows, batch-file

This is a pretty strange problem I have. I want to launch my application at startup, so I created a .bat with this :

> start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\myApp\myApp.exe"

myApp.exe is a C++ application and launches a C# program. When I manually launch myApp.exe the C# app works perfectly. With the .bat myApp.exe is correctly launched but bot the csharp application :

> Windows can not find csharpProgram.exe.Verify that you entered the correct name and try again.

I've looked in the properties of myApp and there is no parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your C++ app expects to find the C# program either in the current directory or else somewhere in the system PATH. When running the app with `START` the current directory is not the same as when manually launching it, so the C# program cannot be found.

Use the `/D` parameter to specify the correct directory, for example:

```
start "" /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\myApp" "C:\Program Files (x86)\myApp\myApp.exe"
```